# Attach IP to VM instance using Node.js API in Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

How to attach an existing statics IP to a VM using the node.js API?

I can do this using [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-access-config), but I can't find where the node API implements this feature on [Address](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Address) and also [VM](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/VM) docs

Comment: You can make a call to the [REST API method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/addAccessConfig) from your node APP. Try it in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.instances.addAccessConfig) so you can know how the request must be formatted

Answer (score 1):

The method you need is not available on the [Node.js Google Cloud library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries) but you can do it with the REST Compute Engine API using Node.js.

You have two options:

> 1.- Add a [new network configuration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/addAccessConfig).
>
> 2.- [Update (just partially if you want) the network configuration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/updateAccessConfig).

Go down completely in the documentation to see code examples (also in Node.js).